# Hiding child elements inside an open details element

Tags: html

We have a `details` and `summary` element, which contains some `div` elements, like so:

```html
<details open>
  <summary>Some summary</summary>
  <div>This content is display</div>
  <div class="hidden">This content is NOT displayed</div>
</details>
```

I have 2 questions that I'm struggling to find the answers to online:

1. Is it "okay" / correct to hide child elements of an **open** details element. In the example, you'll see the the 2nd element is hidden, using `display: none`.
2. Should `details` only have 1 child element, besides the `summary` element? On https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element, it does state the following:

   > Content model: One summary element followed by flow content.

   And flow content is defined by the following: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content

   But I'm not sure if that means I'm allowed multiple flow content's.

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Is it "okay" / correct to hide child elements of an open details element**

- Yes, there's nothing wrong with hiding an element inside a `details` element.
- Actually, you may programmatically toggle the display of those hidden elements just like any other element in the page.

**2. Should `details` only have 1 child element, besides the `summary` element?**

- No, you are not limited to have only one element inside a `details`.
- Also, `details` tags do not require `summary` elements to be rendered correctly. Although it is recommended to have a `summary` element in order to have your own label for the `details` element, you can ditch that `summary` element entirely and the browser will show its own placeholder/label (`Chrome` show the text "Details" if a `details` tag doesn't contain a `summary`).
- In short, you can have as many elements inside a `details` but a **maximum** of **1** `summary` element.

With that being said, let's have a simple demo that illustrates the use of `details` that, on its own, has a bunch of different elements. You can use the button to toggle the `div` that is initially hidden:

```js
const myDIV = document.getElementById('my-div'),
  toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');

toggler.addEventListener('click', () => myDIV.classList.toggle('hidden'));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/** just to make the demo visually appealing */

details {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: .5em .5em 0;
}

summary {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -.5em -.5em 0;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details[open] {
  padding: .5em;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggler">Toggle Initially Hidden DIV</button>
<details open>
  <summary>Some summary</summary>
  <div>This content is display</div>
  <div id="my-div" class="hidden">This content is NOT displayed and its display can be toggled</div>
  <p>I have an image too!<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="display:block;margin: 10px auto 0" width="150"></p>
</details>
```

And here's a demo of a `details` element without a `summary`:

```css
span {
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}


/** just to make the demo visually appealing */

details {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .3em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details[open] {
  padding: .3em;
}
```

```html
<details open>
  <div>i don't have a <span>summary</span> element! You can see that the browser used a its own label</div>
</details>
```

> Learn more about the [`details`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) element.

> Learn more about the [`summary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) element.

Answer (score 0):

From my standpoint

**First question**, yes.

You literally could hide or toggle the display of `details`'s child elements. Because of each different case, e.g., client or system, you may have to display different content `details`. Toggle item description display is a simpler way to achieve that.

**Second question**, depends on how the description is.

In `details` and `summary`, their name represents their meaning and purpose. With UX design, as normal, we can see that we could use them to summarize some details or a long description into a short sentence to express the representative meaning succinctly, similar to `header` or title.

Of course, we don't need `summary` for just one short description or detail.